# After do-release-upgrade to 13.04 from 12.10 I still get informed about 13.04 on log-in via MOTD

Tags: upgrade, 13.04, do-release-upgrade, motd

This was an issue with moving to 12.10 it appears to have resurfaced now with 13.04 i.e. post upgrade to 13.04 you still get the MOTD to upgrade.

I've tried the previous list of fixes for the same issue re move to 12.10 https://askubuntu.com/questions/253844/upgrade-12-04-2-lts-to-12-10-do-release-upgrade-fails-no-new-release-found but they don't seem to work, i.e. there is no /var/lib/update-notifier/release-upgrade-available to remove.

Answer (score 3):

I just "touch" the file **/var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available**

But don't know why this file will not refresh automatically.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "touch"?

Comment: @duxk.gh either remove only the contents of the file; or do `sudo su` and then `cd /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader; rm release-upgrade-available; touch release-upgrade-available`.

Comment: Just remove the file `/var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available`, forget the touch (`/etc/update-motd.d/91-release-upgrade` will recreate it when needed).

Answer (score 0):

In a similar situation I found that there is another file `/run/motd.dynamic` apart from `/run/motd` and the old message persisted `/run/motd`. Both are called by `pam_motd` which states that `/run/motd` is static.

```
# This includes a dynamically generated part from /run/motd.dynamic
# and a static (admin-editable) part from /etc/motd.
```

The solution was just to empty the static file:

```
echo -n "" | sudo tee /run/motd
```