# Ubuntu 12.04 EOL appears in motd after release upgrade to 14.04

Tags: 12.04, motd

I just performed a do-release-upgrade to bring a server from 12.04 to 14.04. The server rebooted at the end of the upgrade. However, when I log in, I am greeted by a contradictory MotD:

> Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-117-generic x86_64)
>
> - Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
>
> New release '16.04.2 LTS' available.
>   Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
>
> This Ubuntu 12.04 LTS system is past its End of Life, and is no longer
>   receiving security updates.  To protect the integrity of this system, it’s
>   critical that you enable Extended Security Maintenance updates:
>    * https://www.ubuntu.com/esm

/var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available only contains the 16.04.2 message (referenced in related question [After do-release-upgrade to 13.04 from 12.10 I still get informed about 13.04 on log-in via MOTD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285887/after-do-release-upgrade-to-13-04-from-12-10-i-still-get-informed-about-13-04-on))

I deleted /run/motd.dynamic so that it would regenerate, but this message has more lives than The Doctor and it must be coming from somewhere else that was not cleaned up in the release upgrade process.

Comment: The referenced question certainly will point someone in the right direction of /etc/update-motd.d/, so the differences I see have to do w/ LTS vs non-LTS and the 99-esm file itself. My googling about this MOTD that would not leave did not bring me to that question, mostly because I did not know what I didn't know before I started searching.

Answer (score 8):

`/etc/update-motd.d/99-esm` contains the undying message/advertisement. This file was created on April 28, 2017, which is the day that 12.04 went End Of Life.

Deleting `/etc/update-motd.d/99-esm` and `/run/motd.dynamic` will cause a refresh of `motd.dynamic` the next time someone logs in.