# Unable to login

Tags: boot, grub2, login

Since I updated Ubuntu, I am not able to go to login screen. It just keeps on loading but it never goes to the login screen. I logged in using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. I typed username and password then this message popped up - "this ubuntu 12.04 system is past its end of life and is no longer receiving security updates. To protect the integrity of this system, it is critical that you enable extended security maintenance updates." followed by a link to ubuntu.com. I just want to login.

Comment: What version did you upgrade to?

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment so I'll at least make the answer explicit and indicate the original question as source:

This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/913149/ubuntu-12-04-eol-appears-in-motd-after-release-upgrade-to-14-04) suggests you delete the files `/etc/update-motd.d/99-esm` and `/run/motd.dynamic` which will cause a refresh in `motd.dynamic` and get you rid of such message.

Comment: Give the man a checkmark. I read "I just want to . . . get rid off GRUB." and almost posted an answer about the virtues of simple, bug free, stable lilo. Glad I paused a moment. LOL